# Custom indexes with C++ matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, indices

I would like to treat C++ bi-dimensional arrays (matrices) in C++ as I can do with R data-frames. What I mean by that is to be able to specify indexes values for the matrices.

For example the natural C++ integer matrix is like this:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 ...
0 1 0 1 0 .
1 3 . . .
2 8 . .
3 . .
4 .
.
.
.
```

I would like to specify indexes in matrix, so they would be like this, for example:

```
  5 7 8 13 24 ...
0 1 0 1 0 .
1 3 . . .
2 8 . .
6 . .
8 .
.
.
.
```

Any advise will be much appreciated.

Comment: so former `Martix[0][0] = 1` will be accessed by an arbitrary index, for example, `Matrix[0][5]`?

Comment: You'll need to define a custom matrix class. Arrays in C++ are primitives for contiguous blocks of memory indexed by contiguous integers.

Comment: The indexing scheme you have in mind here is completely unclear.

Comment: it's not that clear if you haven't used R as well as C++! I think he wants to be able to use custom indices to access the matrix. So something like, use matrix["6"]["5] or matrix ["6","5"] to access the cell in the 4th row and 1st column.

Comment: If it is as TooTone describes, you need an index xlat intermediary, which should not be difficult to implement (and I imagine such a thing is also at least init-level required in R (a language I know *zilch* about) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to switch columns, rows of matrices, you can use some indirection:

```
 indexTable[0][0] = 0; // map row index 0 to 0
 indexTable[1][0] = 5; // map column index 0 to 5
```

and use it like this:

```
 value = matrix[indexTable[0][RowIndex]][indexTable[1][ColumnIndex];
```

or you can write a class to handle this indirection for you.

Answer (score 0):

A `data.frame` in R is essentially just a fancy wrapper for a `list` of columns, and a `list` is – illogically – a close equivalent of `std::map`<sup>1</sup> in C++ (rather than, as its name suggests, of `std::list`).

So in other words you can just use a typedef similar to this to approximate `data.frame`:

```
typedef std::map<int, std::vector<int>> data_frame;
```

… but R classes are actually quite a bit more powerful since they are to some extent generic, support different types inside the data frame, check that all rows have the same length and allow named access for columns and rows. And finally let’s not forget that R has support for working with data frames, pretty-printing them and loading and saving them efficiently.

Depending on what *you* need it’s of course unnecessary to replicate all this in C++ but it’s definitely beneficial to wrap your structure inside a class and provide a proper interface to access it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, a `std::unordered_map`. This requires C++11.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class which

- converts arbitrary specified indices to 0-based incremental indices
- wraps a 1D array such that you can access it as a 2D array using the converted indices

A working example would look something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iterator>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class DataFrame
{
  vector<int> data;

public:
  typedef vector<ssize_t> idx_t;
private:
  idx_t rowIdx;
  idx_t colIdx;

public:
  DataFrame(const idx_t &rowIdx, const idx_t &colIdx)
    : data(rowIdx.size() * colIdx.size())
    , rowIdx(rowIdx)
    , colIdx(colIdx)
  {
    assert(is_sorted(rowIdx.begin(), rowIdx.end()));
    assert(is_sorted(colIdx.begin(), colIdx.end()));
  }

  int& operator()(int i, int j)
  {
    idx_t::iterator itI, itJ;

    itI = lower_bound(rowIdx.begin(), rowIdx.end(), i);
    if(rowIdx.end() == itI || i != *itI) throw out_of_range("could not find specified row");
    itJ = lower_bound(colIdx.begin(), colIdx.end(), j);
    if(colIdx.end() == itJ || j != *itJ) throw out_of_range("could not find specified col");

    return data[distance(rowIdx.begin(), itI)*colIdx.size() +
      distance(colIdx.begin(), itJ)];
  }

  vector<int> & getData() { return data; }
};


int main()
{
  DataFrame::idx_t rI, cI;
  rI.push_back(3);
  rI.push_back(5);

  cI.push_back(2);
  cI.push_back(3);
  cI.push_back(10);

  DataFrame df(rI, cI);

  df(3,2) = 1;
  df(3,3) = 2;
  df(3,10) = 3;
  df(5,2) = 4;
  df(5,3) = 5;
  df(5,10) = 6;

  ostream_iterator<int> out_it(cout, ", ");
  copy(df.getData().begin(), df.getData().end(), out_it);
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The arbitrary indices of each row/column are specified in a vector. To maintain some performance, the code requires that indices are monotonically increasing. (If you have C++11, this is checked in the ctor; if you don't have C++11, then you don't have the `is_sorted` function. Also, this code doesn't verify uniqueness of arbitrary indices.)

When you access the data, it just does a binary search on each vector of indices to find the position in the vector that matches the arbitrary index, and uses that position as the corresponding index to the underlying data. There is a simple conversion from 2D indices to a 1D index.

You may want to check that my index error checking is correct for all combinations of bad/good indices if you need to worry about that.

I'll leave it to you to add more robustness/functionality in terms of `const` accessors, various constructors, etc. If you want to generalize this to arrays of dimension other than 2, I recommend you create a class for just converting arbitrary index to 0-based index, and that will get rid of some of the code repetition I have. There are also other ways to do the conversion of arbitrary index to 0-based index, such as with a `map` like others have suggested. In that case though, there are some problems such as the creator of the `map` would have to ensure that if there are say 10 columns, each index in [0, 10) appears exactly once as a value in the map.